# Authenticate against Azure Computer Vision OCR using user managed identity

Tags: azure, azure-managed-identity

I would like to use a user managed identity in my AKS pod to authenticate with the [Azure Computer Vision OCR API](https://centraluseuap.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/computer-vision-v3-2/operations/5d986960601faab4bf452005).

The managed identity is created and I can see the managed identity in the azure portal

```
{
    "id": "/subscriptions/.../userAssignedIdentities/my-msi",
    "name": "my-msi",
    "type": "Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities",
    "location": "westeurope",
    "tags": {},
    "properties": {
        "tenantId": "<tenant id>",
        "principalId": "<principle id>",
        "clientId": "<client id>"
    }
}
```

and the managed identity has the role "Cognitive Services Contributor" to the Cognitive Service resource with the endpoint
`https://<my-custom-sub-domain>.cognitiveservices.azure.com/`

Now, in my python app running in an AKS pod (which already has the correct `aadpodbinding` label) I would like to send a POST request to
`https://<my-custom-sub-domain>.cognitiveservices.azure.com/vision/v3.2/read/analyze`
with a PDF image to apply OCR on.

Unfortunately, there is not much description on how to do that on the [Cognitive Services documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/authentication?tabs=azure-cloud-shell#authorize-access-to-managed-identities)

I am looking for a python example similar to [this one for authentication against key vault using managed identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-azure-ad-identity#access-key-vault-from-your-web-service)

Answer (score 0):

Adding a pod identity in AKS allows you to acquire tokens using the local token endpoint.

You just need to acquire a token for "https://cognitiveservices.azure.com/" and add that to an Authorization header on the web request to Cognitive Services.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I'm not too late to answer this.
I'm using the C# SDK but I assume that the Python SDK should have equivalent API.
The prerequisite is that the managed identity must be assigned with the **Cognitive Services User** role to the cognitive service you want to use.

```csharp
    // Requires Azure.Identity and Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.ComputerVision
    // ...
    var azCred = new DefaultAzureCredential();

    var token = azCred.GetToken(
                new TokenRequestContext(new[] { @"https://cognitiveservices.azure.com/.default" }))
            .Token;

    ComputerVisionClient client =
        new ComputerVisionClient(new Microsoft.Rest.TokenCredentials(token))
        { 
            Endpoint = endpoint 
        };
```